# Why don't my VideoView show up?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to load a video from a webpage. And display it in a video view.
I use the following code:

```
Context parent = MyParentContext;
String videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c";

VideoView video = new VideoView(parent);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(parent));
addViewToScrollParent(parentView, video);
```

I see no other change than that the textview I add earlier moves from being centered to aligned left. Guessing it creates a video larger than the view or something and keeps it invisible?